# Why do maildirs need the `new` folder?

Tags: maildir

I understand the reason why `tmp` is needed in a [maildir](http://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html): It makes it possible to not have half-written mails in `cur`. However, why is `new` needed?

Couldn't the mails just be dropped into the `cur` folder directly with a name `<uniq>:` or so? As soon as a MUA wants to add flags, it could initialize the `uniq` part. That would probably make things a (well, just tiny) bit simpler to code.